# Find and Replace a row based on Unique ID

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the entire row 2 from the "Temp" sheet.
[image]

And replace the entire row with the corresponding value in column A on the "QuestLog" sheet.
[image]

```vb
Sub UpdateQuest()
    
    Dim SrchSht As Worksheet
    Dim SearchValue, OutPlace
    Set SrchSht = Sheets("QuestLog")
    SearchValue = Sheets("Temp2").Range("A2").Value
    Set c = SrchSht.Range("A:A").Find(what:=SearchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
      
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.Value = Sheets("Temp2").Range("A2").Value
        c.Offset(0, 1) = Sheets("Temp2").Range("B2")
        c.Offset(0, 2) = Sheets("Temp2").Range("C2")
        c.Offset(0, 3) = Sheets("Temp2").Range("D2")
        c.Offset(0, 4) = Sheets("Temp2").Range("E2")
        c.Offset(0, 5) = Sheets("Temp2").Range("F2")
        c.Offset(0, 6) = Sheets("Temp2").Range("G2")
    Else
        MsgBox "Quest ID not found"
    End If
      
End Sub
```

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Fair enough, I have included the code I have used, was going to add a new line for each field, but it doesn't updated in QuestLog

Comment: What happens when you run it?  Have you tried stepping through the code line-by-line?  Does the `Find()` succeed?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyDataToQuestLog()
    Dim searchValue As String
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim temp2Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim questLogSheet As Worksheet
    Dim copyRange As Range
    
    ' Set references to the relevant sheets
    Set temp2Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp2")
    Set questLogSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QuestLog")
    
    ' Set the search value to the value in cell A2 of Temp2 sheet
    searchValue = temp2Sheet.Range("A2").Value
    
    ' Set the search range to the first column of QuestLog sheet
    Set searchRange = questLogSheet.Range("A:A")
    
    ' Find the search value in the search range
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    ' If the search value was found, copy the data from Temp2 sheet to QuestLog sheet
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        Set copyRange = temp2Sheet.Range("B2:G2")
        copyRange.Copy questLogSheet.Range("B" & foundCell.Row)
    Else
        MsgBox "Quest ID not found"
    End If
End Sub
```